# number of ways to arrange n black balls and n white balls on a circle

Tags: combinatorics

Say you have N white balls and N black balls. How many distinguishable ways can I arrange them in a circle? I consider 2 arrangements to be distinguishable if no rotation or reflection can make them the same.

If I were to arrange them in a line, I think there are $(2N)!/4$.

For N=2, there are 2 ways to arrange them: BWBW and WWBB.

For N=3, I think there are 4 ways: WWWBBB, WBWBWB, WWBBWB, WWBWBB

Comment: Hint: for any unique solution on a line, wrap it onto a circle. No any rotation preserves that circle solution. How many different line solutions map to the same circle solution?

Comment: What constitutes a "distinguishable" way?  Would two configurations that differ by a rotation be distinguishable (the group $C_n$)?  How about two configurations that differ by a reflection (the group $D_n$)?  BTW, there is a very general, powerful, and effective method to answer questions of this sort: [Polya's Enumeration Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem).

Comment: I added a clarification about what distinguishable means. I forgot about reflections. Thanks for the link to PET!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following some links from the Polya Enumeration Theorem, I came across this wikipedia page on necklaces and bracelets, which are well studied in combinatorics:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)

Apparently I was describing a bracelet.